# Can I make Generic uDisk write faster?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, hardware-acceleration

I have a Generic uDisk/Flash disk (known as a fake flash drive). Write on 2,4MB/s, and read on 27MB/s. Tested on 20 sample with 20MB file and access 100 times (Linux Benchmark). I'm wishing I can make it run faster so I can create a LiveUSB on it or any bootable os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make the underlying hardware of a flash drive faster.

If your PC has a fast enough processor, you could compress the OS and data to make the apparent throughput higher. On [another post on this site](https://superuser.com/a/413023/116928), Breakthrough writes:

> Assuming your CPU, using some compression algorithm, can compress at C MB/s and decompress at D MB/s, and your hard drive has write speed W and read speed R. So long as C > W, you get a performance gain when writing, and so long as D > R, you get a performance gain when reading.

That said, most popular Linux LiveUSB distributions are already compressed, as they utilize a filesystem called [SquashFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS). If you've already tried flashing a LiveUSB distribution to this flash drive and its performance is unacceptable, you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: Thank you nc4pk. I have created LiveUSB with this uDisk most of it fail except Lubuntu that created using Windows (before I remove it).

It fails to create LiveUSB with any Distro on Linux (run on similar hardware with windows). And success to create Kubuntu with Macbook Pro 8.2 (another fail).

I was Lucky.

Before write and read fail by now.